# python, regex, trouble with negative lookahead and capture of the match

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I have trouble with a regex statement and maybe you can help me there out. My line-variable contains these sorts of strings which I want to manipulate (each for-loop loop one string):

`sip="100.107.0.5" sp="123" dip="100.107.193.1" dp="123" nat-dip="84.2.44.19"`
`sip="100.101.199.1" sp="37690" dip="100.107.0.4" dp="80" nat-dip="100.107.0.4"`

The easy part: When the values in quotation marks after dip= and nat-dip= are equal, then delete the substring nat-dip="..." completely. This is easy doing:

`line = re.sub(r'dip="([^"]+)(" .+)nat-dip="\1" ' ,r'dip="\1\2' ,line)`

But the awful part is this: When the values are not equal, than write the value of nat-dip= in place of the value of dip=. I tried it with negative lookahead and capturing of the value, but it is failing constantly and I'm not able to figure out the faulty part of the code line, which is:

`line = re.sub(r'dip="([^"]+)(" .+)(?!nat-dip="(\1)") ' ,r'dip="\3\2' ,line)`

All I'm getting is this:

`sip="100.107.0.5" sp="123" dip="" dp="123" nat-dip="84.2.44.19"`

... instead of this:

`sip="100.107.0.5" sp="123" dip="84.2.44.19" dp="123"`

What am I doing wrong? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: are you processing html/xml?

Comment: no. raw text. line by line

Comment: @zweiund40 When values don't match, dip's value should be set to nat-dip. Should nat-dip also be removed then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to drop `nat-dip` in both cases, you can use an expression like this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJkurq/3)) in a single replace

```
dip=\"[^\"]*\"([ ]dp=\"[^\"]*\")[ ]nat-dip=\"([^\"]*)\"
Replace Pattern: dip="\2"\1
\2 contains the value of nat-dip,
\1 contains the dp attribute and its value since it's caught in the capture

  dip=\"     # Literal dip="
  [^\"]*     # Any character but ", zero or more times.
  \"         # Literal "
  (          # Open Capture Group 1 (to retain dp)
    [ ]      # a single space, bracketed here for visibility
    dp=\"    # Literal dp="
    [^\"]*   # Any character but ", zero or more times.
    \"       # Literal "
  )          # Close Capture group
  [ ]        # A single space
  nat-dip=\" # Literal nat-dip="
  (          # Open capture group 2 (the value of nat-dip)
    [^\"]*   # Any character but ", zero or more times.
  )          # Close capture group 2
  \"         # Literal "
```

It just always sets the value of dip to nat-dip's value. When they're equal, this is no apparent change. When they're not equal, it changes the value. In both cases, it drops nat-dip.

---

**Update:** Per your comment. There was a chance you'd come and say "No, we need to keep nat-dip in that case.". Ideally, I would use a branch-reset (keeps capture groups consistent, but Python doesn't support that.

So I would use an if-then-else conditional like this `(?(?=lookaround condition)true pattern|false pattern))`. Everything online says python supports such groups but regex101 keeps throwing a pattern error (even with copy-pastes from examples, so no typo), . For this demonstration, I switched to PCRE [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJkurq/5).

```
dip=\"([^\"]*)\"([ ]dp=\"[^\"]*\")(?(?![ ]nat-dip="\1")([ ]nat-dip=\"([^\"]*)\")|[ ]nat-dip=\"([^\"]*)\")

dip=\"([^\"]*)\"([ ]dp=\"[^\"]*\")
(?                            # if
  (?![ ]nat-dip="\1")         # condition
    ([ ]nat-dip=\"([^\"]*)\")   # then do
  |                           # else
    [ ]nat-dip=\"([^\"]*)\"     # do
  )                           # end if
```

The major difference is that the else-do doesn't capture it's contents. It could but it would never use them.

If the condition is met `\3` contains the entire `nat-dip` attribute *and* value. If the condition is not met, `\3` is nothing, `""`

You'll notice that the replace-pattern is `dip="\4\5"\2\3` because whether the `nat-dip value` is in `\4` and `\5` is empty, or vise-versa depends on if the condition is met.

In a branch reset's case, both values could be aligned to \4. Can be a little easier on the eyes. No Regex Flavor supports all the goodies.

But the truth is, I'm only showing you a lookahead solution because you asked, there's no need for even that *in this case*. Simple alternation will do, though it's necessary to reverse the order of the alternation ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJkurq/6)) There are certainly scenarios where conditionals are a lifesaver (especially regarding *lookbehinds*.

**Finally**, it's difficult to do this in more lines of code. We can break it down to a pattern extraction with a callback that uses python's `if` to return the result but we aim for efficiency. For certain though, not everything can be done with one expression. If you wanted to something else with `dp`, that would typically need, and usually make sense, to be in a separate action.

Comment: Er ... Yes. Sometimes one's unable to see the forest for the trees. In the end it's the same and your resolution is more elegant, because of its simplicity.

Comment: But nevertheless. Just out of curiosity. How would it looks like to do the substitution with negative lookahead and the capture of the value. In the past I was faced sometimes with such a problem and I always needed more than one line of code to resolve it. Is there a way to do it as asked?

Comment: @zweiund40 Yeah I totally figured that was the case here. Get sunk in so deep that you're overthinking everything which can be swamp of a thing in regex. **////** Also, updated the answer with alternative methods.

Comment: Uh ... It's much more complex than I thought. It looks great, but I have to confess that I don't understand it in its entirety. I will grasp my regex book and go back to the lab. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is upvoting?

Comment: @zweiund40 You can click my the arrows above or below the "0" next to my answer to upvote or downvote. On any question btw, if you're browsing the site and something is useful to you. Can upvote it.